# Python/Flask function to capture the windows system password?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

My python/flask application needs the windows system password to do some stuff, at the moment it is statically written in the config.py file.
For security reasons though this password should not be stored in the code, it should not be visible.
Is there any python/flask function to capture the windows user password without having to write the static one in the code?
Thank you all.

Comment: I very much doubt you need the windows "system" password (whatever that is). An application running on Windows can simply use a service user. If you need an external process to access part of your Windows server, you should create a specific user with the absolute minimum of access. If your app is running within a VM on your host, simply use local mounts.

Comment: basically the application runs in a VM with Linux, which is in a Windows PC. The application should FTP some files to from the VM to the Windows PC, in order to do that it needs the password of the Windows PC, which is at the moment written in the config.py file. What do you mean with local mounts? Sorry I'm quite a newby on python, how to do thin in practise?

Comment: Update your question with your specific problem and use case.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, storing a password in the code is never a good idea from a security perspective.

Basically you have two possibilities:

- Load the password from a text file and set the access permissions as strict as possible.
- Ask the user for the password when the program starts.

Comment: yes but the password must be changed every 3 months, so I should remember to update the password in the text file manually! would be pretty much the same issue then, stored in a text file or stored in a code, the access to the windows system is already quite strict, it is in a domain network but my boss still says it should not be written in the code. Another solution could be a two-factor authentication with a token? but how to use the token to access the windows system? mah..

Comment: basically the application runs in a VM with Linux, which is in a Windows PC. The application should FTP some files to from the VM to the Windows PC, in order to do that it needs the password of the Windows PC, which is at the moment written in the config.py file.

Comment: I would use a shared folder instead of FTP in that case.